# undefined reference to tf::poseMsgToEigen

Tags: eigen, geometry-msgs, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo.

Inside a service callback, I want to convert a `geometry_msgs::Pose` to `Eigen::Affine3d`. I'm trying to use `tf::poseMsgToEigen`.

My includes are as follows:

```
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h>
#include <eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
```

The relevant part of code is:

```
geometry_msgs::Pose pose;
Eigen::Affine3d transform;  
tf::poseMsgToEigen(pose, transform);
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `tf::poseMsgToEigen(geometry_msgs::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const&, Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0>&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Inside my `CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  tf
  tf_conversions
)
```

and in the `package.xml` I have added the build and exec_depends for the same.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298710/undefined-reference-to-tf::posemsgtoeigen/) by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-26**:
Are you maybe missing `eigen conversion`?

**Comment by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on 2018-07-26**:
@destogl I already included it: `#include <eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h>`. Do I have to include it anywhere else?

**Comment by [Abdulbaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/31967/abdulbaki/) on 2019-04-08**:
I was missing **tf_conversions** and had similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry guys, I was missing `eigen_conversions` inside `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS )` in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Thanks to @destogl for the hint.

---

Originally posted by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) with karma: 136 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-26**:
That is what I meant